# Dynamic selection of component configuration in CRM Web UI

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I did the following:

- Created two configurations C1 and C2.
- Enhanced the View and Classes of a standard Web UI component, added a ComboBox field.

What should I do to select dynamically the configuration? - Example:

- If the user chooses "A" in ComboBox then C1 should be shown.
- If the user chooses "B" in ComboBox then C2 should be shown.

[image: My Config for ZLOY BRole]

Comment: Did you try implementing the BAdI described in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm70/helpdata/en/d3/dda2cab51243d8ab9f33df67330673/frameset.htm)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Sandra.
Yes.
Here's my configuration.
UCCPGMain is for "A" value in ComboBox.
UCCPGMain is for "B" value in ComboBox.
Both config is for ZLOY Business role.

Comment: Can you tell more about how you implemented the BAdI then, or do you think it doesn't apply to your question (and why)?

Comment: Honestly I didn't implemented anything. I just enhanced standard Component, that's all. I was thinking, when I enhancing component the BAdy would be implemented automatically.

Comment: I won't be able to help more (moreover, I don't have a CRM system), but you may find some answers in [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12317384/badi-or-enhancement-spot-to-set-config-keys-dynami.html) (I searched `web ui dynamic configuration BAdI site:sap.com`), especially one possibillity (no BAdI) which is to redefine the method `DO_CONFIG_DETERMINATION` of the class of the concerned view.

Comment: `when I enhancing component the BAdy would be implemented automatically` of course no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DO_CONFIG_DETERMINATION` event of your view, and place something like this:

```
    IF <ComboBox.Value> EQ "A".
      CALL METHOD me->set_config_keys
        EXPORTING
          iv_object_type          = 'your_object_type'
          iv_object_sub_type      = 'your_sub_obj_type'
          iv_propagate_2_children = abap_false.
    ELSE.
      ...config B
    ENDIF.
```

Here object and subobject types are the ones you were prompted while creating custom configuration.

The sample implementation of this method one can find in `BP_HEAD/AccountDetails` standard WebUI component.